# Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.0.0 throwing an exception for Hashtable serialization

Tags: c#, json.net, swagger-ui

When i execute my application it throws an error from **Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.0.0 dll** below error:

`Http Error 500 :
 {
 "Message":"An error has occurred.",
 "ExceptionMessage":"Type System.Collections.Hashtable& is not a dictionary."
 }`

when i use **Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.0.0 dll** it works fine.

Below is the API method called from the Swagger UI (http://localhost:54738/swagger/ui/index) :

```
 [HttpGet]
 public SortedList<int, XElement> getVariableStates(string sInstanceID, [FromBody] ref Hashtable oVarsDic)
 {

 }
```

after updating to Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.0.0 dll ,I am getting HashTable exception.

[image: Descirption Image Here]

Comment: Have you reported this issue to `Newtonsoft`? Is this possibly a known issue with Version 12.0.0.0? Was there any benefit for updating to version 12.0.0.0? If not, just revert to version 11.0.0.0

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of the 12-series? See https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: may it's problem of compatiblity we need to know which technology you are using and his version also ?

Comment: Why are you doing `ref Hashtable oVarsDic` instead of `Hashtable oVarsDic`?  [12.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/12.0.1) has a change *Fixed calling constructors with ref and in parameters* which might be related.  Try getting rid of the `ref`.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your exception details as **text** rather than as a screen shot?  Stack Overflow policy is that you should include your code, error messages, exception details and data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Answer (score 0):

ATTNETION: Newtonsoft.json 12.0.0.0 meaning actually version 12.0.3